# Получение и изменение текущего пароля phpmyadmin (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, settings, настройки

Необходимо создать mysql базу данных. Для этого захожу на http://localhost/pma/index.php
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ввел пользователя root. Получил в результате

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как было сказано в интернете пароль стоит в файле config.inc.php

```
<?php


$i=0;

$i++;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['nopassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'vladdvin861';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'ru';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

?>
```

Пытался заходить без пароля и с паролем vladdvin861 и в результате получал все ту же страницу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом узнать текущий пароль (и как в случае необходимости его поменять)?
После редактирования файла config.inc.php

```
<?php


$i=0;

$i++;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'vladdvin861';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['nopassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'vladdvin861';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'ru';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

?>
```

браузер вывел страницу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При изменении значения параметра с индексом auth_type на http

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'vladdvin861';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['nopassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

получил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @InDevX я не понял, что за приложение mysqladmin (я слышал только про phpmyadmin и mysqld, в пункте 2 пользователь FeelsBadMan В консоли пишете: mysqladmin.exe -u root -p password ) - это раз. А во вторых как сказал FeelsBadMan в последнем пункте
Те, кто не знает пароль, можете узнать его в config.ini.php (я не помню точно, где он расположен, но в этом файле будет строка с вашим паролем и логином) - я привел примеры из каких строк этого файла я брал имя пользователя и пароль.

Comment: Имя пользователя и пароль в INI-файле обязаны в точности соответствовать таковым у учётной записи на MySQL-сервере. Чего, судя по ошибкам, имеет места не быть.

Comment: @Akina а как узнать имя пользователя и пароль учетной записи на MySQL-сервере?

Comment: А кто MySQL устанавливал? вот его и спрашивайте... при установке вводится имя и пароль суперпользователя.